# A query which returns records whose value add up to a certain constant number

Tags: mysql

Im trying to write a query in MySQL. There is a food table in which there are calories corresponding to each food item. What I want is a query which can return all possible combinations of those food items whose calories add upto 150. I have searched it on the internet but couldn't find anything. I know it has something to do with SUM().

Answer (score 1):

This is not efficient to do in SQL.  And, you can't really do this "in general" in SQL.  But, you can get combinations up to a given number.  For instance, the following gets unique combinations with up to four foods:

```
select *
from foods f left join
     foods f2
     on f.foodid < f2.foodid left join
     foods f3
     on f2.foodid < f3.foodid left join
     foods f4
     on f3.foodid < f4.foodid;
```

You can then add a `where` clause to limit this to what you want:

```
where (coalesce(f.calories, 0) + coalesce(f2.calories, 0) +
       coalesce(f.calories, 0) + coalesce(f2.calories, 0)
      ) = 150
```

Note: the combinations are distinct and only contain one instance of each food.